# Calculate an integral $\int_0^1 t^\frac{1}{z}(1-\ln t^\frac{1}{z})dz$

Tags: integration, probability-theory

I came across a question when doing my homework. If independent random variables $X,Y$ and $Z$ has the uniform distribution on $[0,1]$, so does $(XY)^Z$. (Yau College Math Contest 2013)

My try:
$$ P[XY\leq t]=\int_0^1 P[Y\leq \frac{t}{x}]dx=\int_0^t 1dx+\int_t^1 \frac{t}{x}dx=t(1-\ln t)$$
$$ P[(XY)^Z\leq t]=P[XY\leq t^\frac{1}{Z}]=\int_0^1 P[XY\leq t^\frac{1}{z}]dz=\int_0^1 t^\frac{1}{z}(1-\ln t^\frac{1}{z})dz$$

But I have no idea how to deal with the last integral and here comes my question.

> Please calculate$$\int_0^1 t^\frac{1}{z}(1-\ln t^\frac{1}{z})dz$$

If things goes right, the answer should be $t$ as described in the original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly note that $$\frac{d}{dz} \left( t^{\frac1z} \right) = -\frac{\ln(t)}{z^2}t^{\frac1z}$$.

Now we use integration by parts to get that $$\int_0^1t^{\frac1z}\left(1-\frac{\ln t}{z}\right)dz=\int_0^1t^{\frac1z}dz-\int_0^1t^{\frac1z}\frac{\ln t}{z} dz$$
$$=\left[zt^{\frac1z}\right]^1_0+\int_0^1t^{\frac1z}\frac{\ln t}{z}-\int_0^1t^{\frac1z}\frac{\ln t}{z}=t$$

Answer (score 1):

let $1/z=a$, then
$$I=\int_{0}^{1} t^{a}(1-\ln t^{a}) dt$$
Let $t=e^x$, then
$$I=\int_{0}^{1} e^{ax}(1-ax)e^x dx=\int_{-\infty}^{0} e^{bx}-axe^{bx}) dx=\frac{1}{b}-a (\frac{xe^{bx}}{b}-\frac{e^{bx}}{b^2}) |_{-\infty}^{0}=\frac{1}{b}+\frac{a}{b^2}$$Here, $b=a+1$ and lastly we have done integration by part
$$I=\frac{1+2a}{1+a}=\frac{z(z+2)}{(z+1)^2}, z\ne  -1.$$